# Possibility to Travelling together on returning

Tags: air-travel

I am from Sri Lanka and my husband is staying in New Zealand. My husband (alone) wants to come to Sri Lanka  and pick my self and our son and return to New Zealand. We are planning for this trip between 19th and 30th December 2015.We have no visa issues. Anyhow my husband is required to buy a return air ticket for immigration purposes.

To enable three of us to depart Sri Lanka with seats together in the same flight  and in order to get the best deal pls tell, who should buy tickets? Is it my husband (from New Zealand) OR myself (from Sri Lanka)? In what way can we get best results?

Comment: Are you and your son returning back to Sri Lanka?

Comment: whether you buy from NZ or Sri Lanka is less relevant, because both of you will i believe buy the ticket online. as far as the deals are concerned you should probably check sites like skyscanner, momondo or kayak. for getting the seats together on his return flight contacting the airline is I believe an option...

Comment: Book the flight which departure on the same day and have same flight number, then selected the seat asap

Answer (score 0):

You can't have different itineraries on the same booking so you have to make two different bookings. Your best shot is to work directly with the airlines and have them book at the same time and reserve the seats right away.

Unfortunately I found that some airlines are remarkably inept in keeping families together. If for any reason that falls apart, you can negotiate for seating during check in, at the gate, with the flight attendant while you are boarding, and finally with the other passengers.

Contrary to common believe most airline passengers are fairly reasonable people and I have frequently traded seats to allow families to be together. This works best if you book early and reserve "good" seats that are easy to trade.